# JavaScript syntax react route

Tags: javascript

I was going to the react router code here: [modal-gallery](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery)

and came across this syntax

```
const Modal = ({ match, history }) => {
  const image = IMAGES[parseInt(match.params.id, 10)]
  if (!image) {
    return null
  }
  const back = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    history.goBack()
  }
  return (
    <div
      onClick={back}
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)'
      }}
    >
      <div className='modal' style={{
      position: 'absolute',
        background: '#fff',
        top: 25,
        left: '10%',
        right: '10%',
        padding: 15,
        border: '2px solid #444'
      }}>
        <h1>{image.title}</h1>
        <Image color={image.color} />
        <button type='button' onClick={back}>
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My Question is, what type of syntax is this? and how would you convert this into **`ES6 React.Component class`**

Comment: It's called destructuring assignment.

Comment: Please note that this is not JavaScript; and should probably be additionally tagged with [tag:jsx] (even though the phenomenon you ultimately ask about is available in both JavaScript and JSX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a React Stateless Functional Component (React SFC). It's a function, instead of a class.

Basically you don't need/have to convert it to a React.Component class as it's a valid way to declare a React.Component.

A SFC is normally referred to as a dumb component, as it only care about the props passed to it but nothing else. It's a component that is pure (it is not supposed to have any internal state) nor should have any side effects come out from its lifecycle functions.

React recommends that if you don't need internal state, nor lifecycle methods with your component, you should write it as a SFC.

You can have a further look here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure function. You can look at it as just the `render` function of a `React.Component`.

Converting it then becomes easy, just paste the code inside you render function:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match, history } = this.props; // Here you get your props
    const image = IMAGES[parseInt(match.params.id, 10)]
    if (!image) {
      return null
    }
    const back = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation()
      history.goBack()
    }
    return (
      <div
        onClick={back}
          style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)'
        }}
      >
        <div className='modal' style={{
        position: 'absolute',
          background: '#fff',
          top: 25,
          left: '10%',
          right: '10%',
          padding: 15,
          border: '2px solid #444'
        }}>
          <h1>{image.title}</h1>
          <Image color={image.color} />
          <button type='button' onClick={back}>
            Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```